# Getting error of Syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Here, I am importing data in mysql but getting error of syntax.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 1

My code:

```
$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:\orderitems-100081669.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_order_details IGNORE 1 LINES FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@col1,@col3,@col4,@col7,@col8) set orderdet_id=@col1,orderdet_productid=@col3,orderdet_iscase=@col4,orderdet_qty=@col7,  orderdet_price_sold=@col8;")or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
```

Comment: **And the error you are getting is???????**

Comment: Try splitting up the SQL command into multiple lines, just to check the syntax. More importantly, *try it* yourself in a MySQL session, make sure it works there first, *then* copy it to your PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have placed the `IGNORE 1 LINES` at the wrong place.

See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Try

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:\orderitems-100081669.txt' 
INTO TABLE tbl_order_details 
FIELDS 
    TERMINATED BY '\t' 
    ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES 
    TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(@col1,@col3,@col4,@col7,@col8) 
SET orderdet_id=@col1,orderdet_productid=@col3,orderdet_iscase=@col4,orderdet_qty=@col7,  orderdet_price_sold=@col8;
```